# how do use VeeValidation "import" tag when VeeValidation is using cdn

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

Is it possible to get this "import" tag work over cdn ? I included cdn veeValidation script , but i do not know how to get this code line to work `import { Validator } from 'vee-validate';`. Can somebody provide me example?

Comment: If you use CDN, VeeValidate is already available. You can use `Vue.use(VeeValidate);` and 
`VeeValidate.Validator` without importing

Comment: Hehhee tnx ,it is working .